# I need help while inserting in a map of integer and set of a structure

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

The code is :

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

typedef struct
{
   int d_number;
   int o_number;
} d_o_pair;

std::set<d_o_pair> d_o_set;
std::map<int, d_o_set> my_map;

}
```

i want to insert into the map. but i am not able to

. i was using like this : this->my_map[5].insert(make_pair(0, 2)). the compiler throws me error telling no function matches call to insert

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The code appears to be very incomplete, e.g. unmatched right brace at the end. Please do post complete and well-formatted code. Also, describing the problem could help people help you.

Comment: Where is the problem, what errors do you get? From where is the turn() function?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid ALL UPPERCASE identifiers except for macros, where by convention they should be used exclusively. When you use them for ordinary non-macro identifiers (1) you mislead readers into thinking those are macros, (2) you risk inadvertent text substitution due to name collisions with existing macros, and (3) the source code looks like **S H O U T I N G**.

Comment: i want to insert in to the map.but i am not able to. i was using like this :

this->my_map[5].insert(make_pair(0, 2)).
the compiler throws me error telling no function matches call to insert

Comment: "but i am not able to" – are you asking us to teach you C++? That's not how this site works.

Comment: am not telling to teach c++. but why this is throwing error..

Comment: vote down for incomplete code piece. Posted my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Following sample code tell us inserting into map. For inserting to set, you need to overload the '<' operator to define the ordering condition in the structure with a constructor and insert in a similar fashion using insert function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int d_number;
    int o_number;
}d_o_number;

int main()
{
    d_o_number s1;
    s1.d_number  = 100;
    s1.o_number = 1000;

    std::map<int, d_o_number> d_o_map;
    d_o_map.insert(std::pair<int, d_o_number>(0, s1));

    // showing contents:
    std::map<int,d_o_number>::iterator it = d_o_map.begin();
    std::cout << "d_o_map contains:\n";
    for (it=d_o_map.begin(); it!=d_o_map.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second.d_number<<","<<it->second.o_number << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<int, int> d_o_pair;
typedef std::set<d_o_pair> d_o_set;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, d_o_set> my_map;
    my_map[5].insert( std::make_pair( 0, 2 ) );
}
```

Or the following

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

typedef struct d_o_pair
{
    int d_number;
    int o_number;
    bool operator <( const d_o_pair &rhs ) const
    {
        return d_number < rhs.d_number || ( !( rhs.d_number < d_number ) && ( o_number < rhs.o_number ) );
    }        
} d_o_pair;

typedef std::set<d_o_pair> d_o_set;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, d_o_set> my_map;
    my_map[5].insert( { 0, 2 } );
}
```

Comment: @Atul Priya If your compiler supports C++ 2011 then the code will be compiled. Try it yourself. Also it is strange that you marked as the best answer the answer there is said nothing about std::set though in your question you use std::set.